# Examples of user manuals with walk throughs and heavy use of screenshots

Tags: packages

I'm trying to find sources of examples of user manuals written in Latex similar in style to what you would find in a step-by-step software installation guide or in a walk through of a program's features.

Usually people use the `refart` or `memoir` document classes to write documentation that is mostly text-based and very "technical and complete" (e.g. user manuals for Latex packages, documentation for a CLI program etc). However, I haven't seen Latex being used to produce more "layman" documentation, like the one you would write for your grandmother to help her install a program and how to use it ([example](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-iTunes)), with annotated screenshots at every step, inline iconography, plenty of "click File > Open > ..." instructions and the occasional tip or warning box.

[This](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/autorating-calculator-user-guide/fdfgkxkpqczv) is the closest I've been able to find in Latex.

Extra points for packages/macros/tools that might be useful for this kind of user manual authoring.

Comment: In similar situations I use the beamer-package with two columns, On one side is the screenshot, on the 2nd column I have a short description what to do. And in article mode I can create a handout.

Comment: Screenshots are relatively illegible.  Verbatim and listing are better.